# How to access to the current range slider?

Tags: jquery, arrays, rangeslider

I have 2 range inputs (say 100) and want to attach the values of each one to an array e.g.:

```
   <input id="range1" type="range" max="2">
   <input id="range2" type="range" max="2">

    <script>
    var items=new Array();

    items[1]=new Array("dog","horse","cat");
    items[2]=new Array("x","y","z");

    for (x=1;x<3;x++){
        $('#range'+x).rangeslider({
            polyfill : false,
            onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
                console.log(items[x][value]);       
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

The current logic always prints `items[2][blah]` value because at the end of loop the **x=2**. How can I access the current input inside the rangeslider (So extract its ID) (or possibly create a local variable rather than x inside that loop for each slider to get rid of the global variable X)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element and the current value in the `onSlideEnd` event like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // you can also use $('*[id^="range-"]').rangeslider({
  $('.range-slider').rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
      // access to the range-input: this.$element
      // the example shows the id of the range element
      console.log(this.$element.attr('id'));
      
      // access to the current value
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rangeslider { margin-bottom: 35px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.js"></script>

<input id="range-1" class="range-slider" type="range" max="2" />
<input id="range-2" class="range-slider" type="range" max="2" />
<input id="range-3" class="range-slider" type="range" max="2" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this a general way to access a plugin element or the variable "$element" is specially used in rangeslider?

Comment: The element is only accessible in this plugin this way. The developer could also consider another name for the property. I'm not quite sure, but I believe that a plugin can be built in a way that the element is not accessible.